# convergence of integral when space, functions and measures varies with n

Tags: probability, probability-theory, analysis

I am stuck on this for third day now.

I have sequence of random variables $r_n$ from {$-1,1$}$^n$ to real numbers, $r_n$ converges pointwise to $0$ (maybe uniformly I don't know, if it is needed you can assume it). $r_n$ is uniformly bounded.

I have sequence of probability measures $d_{u_n}$ which are uniform distributions on {$-1,1$}$^n$

I want to show that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{-1,1^n}r_n d_{u_n}=0$

I wanted to use dominated convergence theorem but I don't have 1 measure like in the theorem, insted I have sequence of measures.

I wanted to use something like this: [Convergence integral given weak convergence of measures and functions/random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3314036/1078713)
but I don't have 1 space on which I am integrating, instead every integral is on different space (varies with $n$).

How can I formally compute this limit?

Comment: When you write "$r_n$ converges in probability to $0$", you mean $u_n(|r_n| > 0) \rightarrow 0$, right?  It isn't so clear what "converges in probability" means when there are multiple probability measures.  Similarly, how do you define "uniformly integrable" when there are multiple probability measures?

Comment: Yeah you are right, I am getting lost in this. Let's forget about these two statements. Do you know theorem which could help here?

Comment: .,..... ..  ....

Comment: I think we also need to clarify what "pointwise" means here.  Normally it would mean $f_n(x) \rightarrow 0$ for all $x$, but since the domains are all different, I'm not sure what the definition should be now.  I think uniform convergence and convergence in probability might actually be easier modes of convergence to define here.

Comment: yeah I don't know either, I don't understand it, sorry

Comment: This will depend on what precisely you're trying to do/the source of the question, but why not set up a common space which lets you explicitly define things? The natural space here is the set of $\{\pm1\}$-valued sequences. The key observation is that its possible to stitch together the $d_n$s (since for $m > n, d_m( X_1^n = x_1^n) = 2^{-n} = d_n(X_1^n = x_1^n),$ where $x$ is a sequence and $x_1^n$ is the first $n$ entries), which essentially yields a stochastic process interpretation:

Comment: (contd.) you have a sequence of iid $\pm1$ random variables, $d_n$ is the induced law on the first $n$ of these, and $r_n$ depend only on the first $n$ of these. Note that because $r_n$ depends only on the first $n$ entries, $\int r_n d_n = \mathbb{E}[r_n(X)],$ and pointwise convergence to $0$ is meaningful, and of course boundedness is enough to hit this with the DCT.

Comment: Note btw, that in essence I'm defining a model of the situation of the question. It may not be the right model to capture the scenario you are interested in. The key point though is to find such a model, after which the things you say start making mathematical sense, and you can use the tools at hand.

Comment: I think it should be $\int r_nd_n=E[r_n(X_n)]$, X depends on n, X_n is a random variable with uniform distribution on {-1,1}^n in infinite product of {-1,1} as you described. And this can be seen for example by law of unconcious statististician for measure theoretic formulation on wikipedia. However we get this E(r_n(X_n)) with respect to what measure? I mean E is an integral with respect to some measure, unfortunately this measure still depend on n I think. So we are still stuck with something like integral over some space of sequence of functions with respect to sequence of measures.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that the definition of convergence in probability is that $u_n(|r_n| > \varepsilon) \rightarrow 0$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$.  Since $r_n$ is uniformly bounded, let $K$ be such that $|r_n| \le K$ for all $n$.

Given $\varepsilon > 0$, let $N$ be such that $u_n(|r_n| > \varepsilon) < \varepsilon$ for all $n \ge N$.  Then, for all such $n$,
\begin{align*}
\left|\int_{\{-1,1\}^n} r_n du_n\right| &= \left|\int_{\{-1,1\}^n} r_n 1_{\{|r_n| > \varepsilon\}} du_n + \int_{\{-1,1\}^n} r_n 1_{\{|r_n| \le \varepsilon\}} du_n \right| \\
&\le \int_{\{-1,1\}^n} |r_n| 1_{\{|r_n| > \varepsilon\}} du_n + \int_{\{-1,1\}^n} |r_n| 1_{\{|r_n| \le \varepsilon\}} du_n \\
&\le \int_{\{-1,1\}^n} K 1_{\{|r_n| > \varepsilon\}} du_n + \int_{\{-1,1\}^n} \varepsilon 1_{\{|r_n| \le \varepsilon\}} du_n \\
&= K u_n(|r_n| > \varepsilon) + \varepsilon u_n(|r_n| \le \varepsilon) \\
&\le (K+1) \varepsilon.
\end{align*}

Since $\varepsilon > 0$ was arbitrary, we thus conclude $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  \int_{\{-1,1\}^n} r_n du_n = 0$.